# How can I obtain z-values instead of t-values in linear mixed-effect model (lmer vs glmer)?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, t-distribution, z-statistic

I am wondering why in my `lmer` model the `summary()` only yields t-values rather than z-values, such as here:

```
model <- lmer(area~Register+(1|subject), data = ev)
summary(model)

Linear mixed model fit by REML 
t-tests use  Satterthwaite approximations to degrees of freedom ['lmerMod']
Formula: area ~ Register + (1 | subject)
   Data: ev

REML criterion at convergence: 166.3

Scaled residuals: 
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-1.60697 -0.46989  0.06558  0.69561  1.41818 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 subject  (Intercept) 1.185    1.089   
 Residual             1.747    1.322   
Number of obs: 45, groups:  subject, 15

Fixed effects:
                        Estimate Std. Error      df t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)              11.2827     0.4421 31.6600  25.522  < 2e-16 ***
RegisterIDS               1.2339     0.4826 28.0000   2.557  0.01627 *  
RegisterLombard\nSpeech   1.3630     0.4826 28.0000   2.824  0.00863 ** 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ?**?0.001 ?*?0.01 ??0.05 ??0.1 ??1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) RgsIDS
RegisterIDS -0.546       
RgstrLmbrdS -0.546  0.500
```

I am wondering in what circumstances will R report z-values? I saw in some papers that people obtained z-values with binominal dependent values, is this the only circumstance that z-values appear?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**tl;dr** `lmer` (linear mixed models) labels this column as a "t statistic", while `glmer` (generalized linear mixed models) labels it as a "Z statistic", but they're actually the same number. This mirrors the difference between the way `lm` and `glm` report their output.

The "t statistics" reported by `lmer` (assuming a Gaussian distribution of observations conditional on fixed and random effects) and the "Z statistics" reported by `glmer` (assuming binomial, Poisson, etc. ... distributions ...) are really the *same number*, i.e. the point estimate divided by the estimate of its standard error (you can check this via `cc <- coef(summary(fitted_model)); cc[,"Estimate"]/cc[,"Std. Error"]`). In a standard least-squares fit, we can prove that this quantity is $t$-distributed, and we can derive the corresponding degrees of freedom exactly. We can also do this for *some* linear mixed models (i.e. balanced designs with single or nested random effects only). For more complex linear mixed models there are various approximations (Satterthwaite, Kenward-Roger; see the `pbkrtest` or `lmerTest` packages) for deriving the approximate distribution of $\bar x/\hat \sigma$.

For generalized linear models, the finite-size corrections are less well understood and disseminated; the sampling distribution of $\bar x/\hat \sigma$ for non-Normal responses is *not* t-distributed even in simple cases (it's also not Z-distributed, except asymptotically).  There is some literature on approximate finite-size corrections under the rubric of *Bartlett corrections*, but the standard practice in GLMs is to report these values as "Z statistics" and assume (when calculating p-values) that people know that they're assuming the sample size is large.

Comment: Excellent answer! Thanks! One issue now I am concerning is: what is the difference between linear mixed model and generalized linear model? And in what circumstance should I choose glmer?

Comment: that's a much more general question. Generalized linear (mixed) models handle some kinds of non-Normal data. Typically you want to use GL(M)Ms if your data are of particular discrete types (binary, counts, proportions) that can't easily be transformed to be Normal.

Comment: I see, thanks! That is why in some papers I have read people usually put family = “binominal” in glmer and that where I saw they got z values.

Comment: if my answer resolved your question you are encouraged to click the check-mark to accept it ...